# Python Lists and Loops/Changing Elements

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have created a while-loop (below) that accesses each element of the list and prints its square. Now, how would I change this program so that it replaces each element by it's square.  For example: If x = [2,4,2,6,8,10], then x would be changed to x = [4,16,4,36,4,64,100]

```
    print("Enter any into the list: ")
    x = eval(input())
    n=0
    while n < len(x):
        print("The square of", x[n], "is", x[n]**2)
        n += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the `while` loop:

```
print("Enter any into the list: ")
x = eval(input())
n=0
while n < len(x):
    print("The square of", x[n], "is", x[n]**2)
    x[n] = x[n] ** 2
    n += 1
```

It isn't a good idea to use `eval()`, though.  You should use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

print("Enter any into the list: ")
x = ast.literal_eval(input())
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You would almost do the same thing, except with a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(x)):   # x must be a list
    x[i] **= 2
```

You could also set it in the `while` loop:

```
print("Enter any into the list: ")
x = eval(input())
n=0
while n < len(x):
    print("The square of", x[n], "is", x[n]**2)
    x[n] **= 2
    n += 1
```

Comment: `range()` does not require a first argument.  The default start is `0`.

Comment: Didn't know that... but I like the 0 there just for readibilty

Comment: How would I create a modified copy of a lists that creates a new list of the squares of the integers. In other words there will be the original list and a new list with the squares?

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [n**2 for n in x]
```

List comprehensions are your friends.